# How to get the surrogate splits in a ctree model, party package in R

Tags: classification, party

I am trying to use `ctree` from `party` to get a conditional classification tree. The tree worked well, but I just can't find any infomation about how to see the results of the surrogete splits from this tree.

The script for the model is:

```
ctree(occurrence ~ ., data = type, controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
```

Could anyone help me to see the surrogete splits? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I recommend that you use the reimplementation of `ctree()` in the `partykit` package which has been streamlined and improved and also has a much cleaner infrastructure for the trees. This is helpful for extracting the surrogate splits. As a reproducible example let's use

```
library("partykit")
ct <- ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris, maxsurrogate = 3)
```

Now every inner node of the tree in `ct` has a `$surrogates` element of (up to) 3 `partysplit` objects. For example, if I want to extract the 2nd surrogate split in the 3rd node, I can do:

```
nodeapply(ct, ids = 3, function(n) n$surrogates[[2]])
## $`3`
## $varid
## [1] 2
## 
## $breaks
## [1] 6.1
## 
## $index
## [1] 1 2
## 
## $right
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $prob
## NULL
## 
## $info
## NULL
## 
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "partysplit"
```

This means that this surrogate splits in the `varid = 2` from `model.frame(ct)` (i.e., `Sepal.Length`) at the splitpoint `breaks = 6.1`. The smaller values go to the first child node and the rest to the second child node.

To obtain this information in human-friendly form you can do:

```
sp32 <- nodeapply(ct, ids = 3, function(n) n$surrogates[[2]])
character_split(sp32[[1]], model.frame(ct))
## $name
## [1] "Sepal.Length"
## 
## $levels
## [1] "<= 6.1" "> 6.1"
```